# Can I split a list in Haskell using a delimiter?

Tags: haskell

I have a text file which contains the following:

```
1 kg g
5000 m km
98.6 f c
```

I am supposed to read the file and convert the number from the first unit to the second and write the outputs in another text file, so the end result should be:

```
1000
5
37
```

My code so far is:

```
import System.IO  
import Control.Monad

main = do
    contents <- readFile "Readings.txt"
    let ls = lines contents
    print $ ls


    when (length contents > 0) $
        writeFile "Outputs.txt" contents
```

Output:

```
["1 kg g\r","5000 m km\r","98.6 f c\r"]
```

Currently I am trying to split the list ls by spaces so I can have each element in the row alone.
Is my thinking process right? or can I approach this in a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard `words` function will split on spaces:

```
> words "1 kg g"
["1","kg","g"]
```

For other delimiters, there is the `Data.List.Split` module from the `split` library.

---

To get rid of the `\r` from your DOS-format text file, use something like the following instead of `readFile`:

```
main = done
    handle <- openFile "Readings.txt"
    hSetNewlineMode handle universalNewlineMode
    contents <- hGetContents handle
    ...
```

Comment: words splits strings that you enter manually in the code. At least that's my understanding.
I want to split strings in the list.

Comment: You can apply `words` to *any* string value. If you have a list of strings, you can map `words` over it: `map words ["foo bar", "1 2"] == [["foo", "bar"], ["1", "2"]]`. `words` and `lines` are very similar: the former splits on whitespace, the latter on newlines. (They differ in how they treat consecutive occurrences of their respective delimiters, though: `lines "1\n\n2" == ["1", "", "2"]`, while `words "1\n\n2" == ["1", "2"]`.)